# java - Auto size JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, size

I am creating a minesweeper game in Java, and I want my JFrame to be in the exact size to be able to see all of the buttons and without margin.
I have tried to calculate the size per number of tiles, and it didn't really work. Is there any way I can make the JFrame to "auto size" by the size of the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

May be try this.

```
((JFrame)myButton.getTopLevelAncestor()).pack();
```

Where myButton is the button whose text is modified during execution.

Comment: I am creating 100 buttons, to what button do you refer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` method for the JFrame. For the `width` and `height`, create an `int counter` which stores the number of tiles you have on screen. I am guessing you are using buttons are the tiles? So if the user chooser the difficulty, they are basically choosing the number of tiles that the board will be. e.g. easy mode: 20x20 tiles, medium mode: 50x50 tiles, etc. So if they choose easy, set the counter number (in the `actionListener` of the "Easy Mode" button to '20'. Then do `yourJFrame.setBounds(0,0,counter,counter);` This should work for a square board.

If you want a different shape, change the above counter to "counterX" for x-axis. Then make another `int counterY'. This is for the y-axis. In this case, your code will be`yourJFrame.setBounds(0,0,counterX,counterY);`

This should work. Have fun!

Comment: For easy mode I am using 10x10 tiles, so the command should be `this.setBounds(0,0,10,10);`
This is displaying only the JMenuBar I have.

Comment: @roydbt to set the size of the JFrame, use my method. So for the size of the JFrame, set the values of `counterX` and `counterY` to 10. Then use `.setBounds(x, y, counterX, counterY);`. The benefit of this is that if you ever want to add more difficulties, it will be a lot easier because you will only have to change the values of the counters (which will be super-quick). Also, an Idea could be to use a JSlider to set the number of tiles. When the slider is moved up, the values of the counters can be incremented by `1` each time. Then the user can set their own difficulty instead of presets

Comment: http://imgur.com/IdxiOak This is the final program. The code is this:
`int counterX=10,counterY=10;
setBounds(0,0,counterX,counterY);`
From within the constructor.